# Thinner border in printing html table

Tags: css, html

I need to print a large data lot in a table.  I need to create a html table to pack that data.  But, when printing the html table the table border is too thick.  I tried using the border-collapse attribute, but when printing it does not work.  When the borders are too thick I'm unable to handle and pack my data nicely into one page.  When I use Firefox, it gives me expected result.  Chrome does not.  What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Please provide an example of your code or a working example.  In addition, please go back to your previous questions and accept the most helpful answer.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: yeah. sorry about that. thankx  James,jadarnel27, Truth for putting me to right path. Here is the code .
http://jsfiddle.net/6vsKz/7/embedded/result/ in "jsfiddle"
i need to make more thinner the table border as well as cell borders